# Cant download HTTP files through a python request

Tags: python, network-programming

I have been working on this program which basically sends an HTML request to the specified server, but each time I run it to send a GET request it responds with a 404 not found page of that site. Can anybody please guide what am I doing wrong out here? I tried copying the Firefox HTML request file and sending that still no use.

```
import socket

server,port = 'google.com',80
ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)
print (ip)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((server,port))
request = 'GET /HTTP/1.1\nHost: '+str(ip)+'\n\n'
print(request)
sock.sendall(request.encode())
while True:
   data = ' '
   data = sock.recv(4096)
   if data == ' ':
       break
    print(data.decode())
```

And also what are the applications of socket module apart from creating remote servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is your request.  First, you need a space after that first /.  Second, for the host, it should be www.google.com, not an IP address.

```
request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1 \nHost: www.google.com\n\n'
```

Also, you should change that first line to www.google.com, since it will redirect you there anyway:

```
server,port = 'www.google.com',80
```

Comment: Oh! It worked! Now I loaded the html into firefox how can I send a search query to google.com with this python?

Comment: You are going beyond the scope of your original question, and you are doing it the hard way anyway.  There are libraries that do all this for you, and they are much easier to deal with.  For instance, Beautifulsoup.  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/?

Comment: Yeah, I know! I thought I could somehow send a Get or Post requests to submit forms. Just curious! Thanks Though.

Comment: It can be done, but I have little knowledge of how http requests are done on that level.  I leave that up to other people.  I used to mess around with that stuff like 20 years ago, but I found it to be too big of a pain to implement myself, especially when there are good libraries that make it so easy.